# Execute precondition only once before running behave tests

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, python-behave

I would like to run `precondition` only once before running a bunch of tests (defined in scenario outlines).

Let's say I've `feature file` like this:

```
Background:
    Given Fan is powered

#Test to check fan speed
@TEST_FAN-1 @SuperFan
Scenario Outline: Checking fan speed
    Given fan is not running
    When send speed command with <speed>
    Then fan is running with <speed>


    Examples:
        | speed |          
        | 5     |
        | 50    |
        | 100   |
```

I've defined `Given Fan is powered` as below:

```
@given("Fan is powered")
def step_impl(context):
    assert conetxt.fan.is_powered
```

This precondition is executed before every test defined in [scenario outline](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gherkin.html#scenario-outlines).
Is there a way to run it only once?

Comment: Maybe you can run that in either of the hook functions before_all or before_feature in environment.py

Comment: Unfortunatly not, that is not an option, because whole feature file (including preconditions) will be downloaded from Jira.

Comment: Try to implement it as a fixture on a feature level. It will be then executed once at the beginning of the feature file: `https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fixtures.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to add a context attribute in `before_all` to keep track of whether the step in question has executed before or not. This will still show the step in the logs but subsequent attempts will be no-ops.

```py
def before_all(context):
    context.precondition_cache = set()

@given("fan is powered")
def step_impl(context):
    if "fan is powered" not in context.precondition_cache:
        # power up the fan
        context.precondition_cache.add("fan is powered")
```